# Reference request about the representations of the group $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, projective-geometry

Is there a review/exposition of the representation theory of $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ ?  Like an enumeration of its irreducible representations and their dimensions as a function of $q$?

Comment: It's complex character table is well known, I think it was known to Frobenius.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeff Adams has comprehensive notes on his website:
http://www.math.umd.edu/~jda/characters/characters.pdf

The irreducible characters of the groups SL(2), PGL(2), GL(2) and PSL(2) over finite fields are described.

The problem for PSL(2) was originally solved by Frobenius in his 1896 paper: Über Gruppencharaktere. It is the first article in Volume 3 of his collected works (Gesammelte Abhandunglen, Band III). On the last page of this article, I found the table:[image]

Comment: The comment on the last line of Frobenius's paper is nice: $\mathrm{PSL}(2, F_3)\cong A_4$ and $\mathrm{PSL}(2, F_5)\cong A_5$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! On page 12 can you kindly explain how to read it that table? What is the "dimension", "size", "number", "number" ? Can you kindly clarify the notation?

Comment: The number of conjugacy classes depends on $q$, so you can't really list them all separately. Fortunately, it is possible to group the classes into types; all the classes of the same type have the same size. This is what "size" and "number" refer to for the classes - if number is n and size is s, then there are n classes of size s. For representations again a similar principle holds. Both classes and representations of a given type have parameters which appear in the character formulas. To get the hang of the notation used in the parameters, you have to read through the earlier sections.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try to decipher this! BTW, what I am looking for is this : I am looking for a sequence of groups of increasing size such that they all have a representation in terms of permutation matrices and the dimension of the smallest non-trivial irreducible representation in these permutation representations is as large as possible. Any help?

Comment: In this case, the group $PSL(2, q)$ has order $q(q^2-1)/2$. A representation of dimension $q+1$ is an irreducible representation which occurs in a permutation representation (the representation induced from a trivial representation of the subgroup of upper triangular matrices).

Comment: The *only* example with the square-root optimality that I can find is this,

GL_1(F_prime-power)
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_general_affine_group_of_degree_one_over_a_finite_field

As far as I can see there is no other example out there!

So it looks like a really unique property to have!

It would be very useful if we can prove this thing in the sense of a classification theorem to show that may be this is all that we have!

Answer (score 7):

How about the [MAA article of J. E. Humphreys](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/representations-of-sl-2p)?

Comment: Is it behind the pay wall?

Comment: @FanZheng I believe following the link would answer your question

Comment: Maybe the text before Humphrey's article is worth reading and pondering, isnt'it ?

Answer (score 7):

Cedric Bonnafe wrote a book entitled "Representatons of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$" that has evertyhing you are looking for.